# Web app using servlets (LDAP connection )

Tags: html, jsp, web, ldap

I am really new to this. I am a student at university working on a project which is about making a single form that I connect to with `LDAP`. I connect with my university username and password. I have to build a `servlet` for that connection. I completed the part of making a login form using `web.xml`.
Any ideas on how I connect with LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, J2EE containers do not all use the same process to allow this type of action.

If you are using Tomcat, we have an example:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP

The concepts are the same for all (?) J2EE containers but the implementation / configuration is not consistent.